# Unable to import numpy, DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: pandas, numpy, cx-freeze

i builded a tkinter app where i use pandas and the executable runs fine on my computer and in computers with anaconda env, but everytime i try to run on computers without python i get the following error.

[image: error message]

setup.py

```py
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os.path
import sys
import nltk
import numpy

nltk.download('punkt', download_dir='nltk_packages') 

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')


base = None

# if sys.platform == 'win32':
#     base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [Executable("main.py", base=base)]


packages = ['sqlalchemy.dialects','sqlalchemy.sql.default_comparator','numpy']
options = {
    'build_exe': {    
        'packages':packages,
        "includes": ["numpy","numpy.core._methods"],
        'include_files':['nltk_packages','stemmedStop.csv','stemmedWhite.csv',os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
           os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll') ]},


}

setup(
    name = "Carrefour Nlc",
    options = options,
    version = "0.0.1",
    description = '<any description>',
    executables = executables
)
```

[i tried this solution with no sucess](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/541)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have multiple NumPy version.
Do - pip3 uninstall numpy - repeatedly until there is no more numpy.
Then - pip install numpy - that should solve it